# Why is my webpart Accordion only displaying half of my html code?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, embedded, accordion

I'm creating a FAQ and my webpart embedded code is only displaying the first six questions in my code?

Here's a screenshot of what it displays even though my html code has 12 questions.

[image]

My spacing between each accordion is just crazy as well. Too much spacing which I can't figure out...

[image: Spacing]

I'm a beginner when it comes to SharePoint so any suggestions to get all my FAQs to display would be great!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>I would like to be a supplier for the City. What is the first step?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>The very first step to become a supplier is to register your business on Bonfire. You will start receiving notifications for Bids and Solicitations.</p>
  </div>
 <h3>What is Bonfire?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Bonfire is our solicitation portal. It is where the City of Dallas posts bid and solicitation opportunities.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>How do I register to received notices of bidding opportunities in Bonfire?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>To ensure you receive the proper notices, include all commodity codes related to your business.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Do I need my Bonfire vendor number?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>No. Bonfire is strictly for viewing and participating in bids and solicitations for the City. </p>
  </div>
<h3>How do I reset my Bonfire password?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>For instructions to reset your Bonfire password click here </p>
  </div>
  <h3>How do I fill out an Online BidTable? </h3>
  <div>
    <p> For instructions to fill out an online bid table, click here </p>
  <div>
<h3>Where can I find additional answers and Bonfire training guides?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Bonfire has a learn and tour option available. For more information, click here</p>
  </div>
<h3>How do I find out about Bid Meetings and other special events?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>For more bid meetings and other special events, click here:</p>
</div>
<h3>How do I find out who was awarded a project after a solicitation has closed?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Please see below regarding awarded projects:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>For older projects, please submit an open record request via City's WEBAPP</li>
      <li>Beginning January 01, 2020 the bid table will be posted on the solicitation in Bonfire or contact.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h3>I have been awarded a contract by the City of Dallas, how do I register for payment?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Please see below regarding awarded contracts</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A City of Dallas customer vendor number is required.</li>
      <li>In order to receive payment for goods and services delivered you may email  in order to get a registration form or register online through the self-service portal.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h3>I have registered on the City's self-serve site and have not received my customer vendor number, what do I do?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>In the event that you do not receive your vendor number, you can call or email, have your tax ID available in order to search your vendor number.</p>
  <div>
<h3>rWhen do I need my City supplier number, and how do I reset it if I need to?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>A City supplier number is only needed once you have been awarded or need payment from the City. If you have lost your login information, please call or reach out to  Please have your tax ID available in order to search your vendor account.</p>
  <div>
<h3>How do I find out more information about MWBE?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>In order to find out more about MWBE you can reach out to our Business Team, via</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not SharePoint-related at all. However, you are missing to close a div tag. And regarding the whitespace  in your accordion (and other options), you should check the API for the jQuery accordion. https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-heightStyle

Comment: Hey Chris, sometimes getting some fresh eyes really helps lol. Do you happen to know where I'm missing the div?

Comment: Oh man! Found the Div! Put this as answer and I'll accept! Spent hours and you found it! :)